# Access this.$slots while using v-slot (scoped-slot)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In a specific use-case, I have to access the DOM element inside a slot to get its rendered `width` and `height`. With normal slots, this works by accessing `this.$slots.default[0].elm`.

Now I added a scoped-slot to access data inside the component, which led to `this.$slots` being empty and breaking my code.

How is it possible to access the DOM element of a slot that is using a slot-scope?

Basic example code (notice while using a scoped-slot, `this.$slots` results in `{}`; while using a normal slot, it results in `{default: Array(1)}`):

`App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld v-slot="{ someBool }">
      <p>{{ someBool }}</p>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </HelloWorld>
    <HelloWorld>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </HelloWorld>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

`HelloWorld.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <slot :someBool="someBool" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      someBool: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$slots);
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$scopedSlots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots), which includes both scoped slots and non-scoped slots:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$scopedSlots.default())
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJMzaqm?editors=1010)

Comment: This does not solve the problem since while using scoped slots the `.elm` property is `undefined`. But I need it to calculate the width and height of the content.

Comment: @SUBHUMAN I'm assuming `.elm` is a custom property of the component you're selecting. `$scopedSlots.default()` returns the same array result as it did originally with `this.$slots.default`, so the equivalent of `this.$slots.default[0].elm` is `$scopedSlots.default()[0].elm`.

Comment: According to this github issue (https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9580) accessing the `.elm` in scoped slots it is not reccommended since that is "changing"

Comment: I have to clarify that with the following code I got what I was looking for so I will mark your answer as correct:
```js
const { context } = this.$scopedSlots.default()[0];
this.slotDomElement = context.$children.find((vnode) => vnode._uid === this._uid).$el;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not directly related but wanted to share how to access slot values.

#### resources/js/components/product/Filter.vue

```
<template>
    <span class="ml-5">
        The Slot Values: <span class="text-yellow-400">{{filterValues}}</span>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            filterValues: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.filterValues = this.$slots.default()[0].children
    }
}
</script>
```

#### resources/views/products.blade.php

```php
...
   <product-filter-vue>Instrument, FX</product-filter-vue>
...
```

[image]